# What fraction of knots are ribbon knots?

Tags: knot-theory

Pardon the naive question.
Perhaps there are several different variants of my question, but
essentially I am seeking to know whether [ribbon knots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_knot) are
vanishingly rare among all knots, or a positive fraction of all knots.
I am sure this is known to the cog*knot*scenti...
 
 
 
[image: PrimeKnots]

---

If the question needs to be specific:

> **Q**. Among prime knots of crossing number $n$ ([OEIS A002863](http://oeis.org/A002863)),
>   what is the fraction that are ribbon knots, as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Surely they are vanishingly rare. The Fox-Milnor condition on the Alexander polynomial (that it factors as $f(t)f(t^{-1})$) should already show that slice knots are rare.

I don't know a proof, however.

Comment: @DylanThurston: Thanks for pointing me to that nice symmetry condition on ribbon (and slice) knots.